# Simplify numpy.dot within loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, array-broadcasting

Is it possible to simplify this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random_sample((40, 3))
data_base = np.random.random_sample((20, 3))
mean = np.random.random_sample((40,))
data = []
for s in data_base:
    data.append(mean + np.dot(a, s))
```

`data` should be of size (20, 40). I was wondering if I could do some broadcasting instead of the loop. I was not able to do it with `np.add` and some `[:, None]`. I certainly do not use this correctly.

Comment: `np.dot(database, a.T)` gives a (20,40) array; `mean` can be added to that since the (40,) shape broadcasts to (1,40) to (20,40).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data` creates a (20,40) array:

```
In [385]: len(data)
Out[385]: 20
In [386]: data = np.array(data)
In [387]: data.shape
Out[387]: (20, 40)
```

The straight forward application of `dot` produces the same thing:

```
In [388]: M2=mean+np.dot(data_base, a.T)
In [389]: np.allclose(M2,data)
Out[389]: True
```

The `matmul` operator also works with these arrays (no need to expand and squeeze):

```
M3 = data_base@a.T + mean
```

Comment: Great! Is there a speed benefit from using `matmul`?

Comment: No significant differences in a simple case like this.

Comment: if `data_base = np.random.random_sample((25, 3))`, the result of np.dot is not a (25, 40) but a (40, 25) matrix. So I had to do: mean+np.dot(data_base, a.T).T